# What are the standard encodings in today's operating systems?

Tags: encoding

What are the standard encodings in Mac, Unix and others?

I know that if my friend who uses Windows sends me a file, it'll most probably be encoded in `cp1251`. So in `emacs`, I can do: `revert-buffer-coding-system` and will choose `cp1251`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no "*the* standard encoding", you have *many* of them.

**[UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), an Unicode encoding, is the most commonly used these days.** It is the default on most Linux distributions, as well as many email clients on other platforms. On Windows, "Unicode" usually refers to UTF-16, which is just another representation of the same Unicode.

Other encodings have been slowly falling into disuse, due to their limitations and inability to use multiple languages in the same file.

- The most "standard" of them would be the **[ISO 8859](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859) encodings, mainly ISO 8859-1** for "Western Europe".
- Their [Windows counterparts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#Windows_.28ANSI.29_code_pages) are very similar; the most common is ***Windows-1252* aka *cp1252*, a superset of ISO 8859-1**. (Your *cp1251* is for Cyrillic script.)
- Other encodings such as KOI8-R and Shift-JIS are also used.

See also a [list of character encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Common_character_encodings).

A Python script named [chardet](http://chardet.feedparser.org/) is able to accurately guess the encoding used on given files.

Comment: UTF-8 is the default on OSX

Comment: @grawity: It looks like chardet doesn't have a CLI interface. Is that true?

Comment: @Adobe: True, but using `chardet` from Python interactive mode is easy. `import chardet; data = open("myfile").read(); print chardet.detect(data)`

Comment: @grawity: Thanks - using Your solution I've made it a python script - so now it has a CLI interface. I've put the script [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455976/emacs-is-there-a-way-to-determine-coding-system-of-a-file/7529438#7529438). Well - thanks again - it's so nice to have such an ability to find out the encoding automatically.